# Recommend .NET data access layer/middle tier

Tags: .net, design-patterns, data-access-layer, data-access

I'm currently creating an MVC application that will likely to expand to include a silverlight, wpf and possible windows phone all using the same data.

So I've created a class library to keep all my objects in and I've created the MVC app.

My question is what would be the best way to access the data? Taking into account possible expansion in the future.

Should I use web services/WCF?
RIA Services?
Remoting?
Or something else.

What have people used in the past and what do you recommend?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've written a bunch of applications that had a web app and a winform/smart client (so far no phone apps) that shared data.  We've always opted for a web service/wcf app as method to deliver the data.  It's a simple architecture (simple is good), reliable and easy to maintian.

Answer (score 0):

Remoting is definately not advised since it's superseeded by WCF. 
Maybe the [ADO.NET Data Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/default.aspx) is something for you. With Data Services you can create a REST based service. Easy to implement and easy to use.

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee730343.aspx) you can read what Microsoft says about it.